# Where can I find GDAL Python bindings for Python 3.4?

Tags: gdal, python-3

I am using python 3.4 for development and I need GDAL python bindings for python 3.4. I have already gone through this [site](http://www.gisinternals.com/index.html), but I can only find up to python 3.3?

Comment: Install: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython
mentioned by AKhorus above but I can not open the site................ i do not have enough reputation to comment AKhorus'answer his answer mentioned that the install instruction site is
https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython
but i can not open this site

Comment: Welcome to SE.  To write a good answer it's not best practice just to mention another person answer as it could get removed.  Try writing a complete answer that others with the same problem could follow in the future.

Comment: And if you try http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython you will get informed that the site is up for others.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/94585)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/94585)

Answer (score 5):

If you are on Windows you could give the [precompiled wheels by Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) a try, he has a stable 1.11 with bindings for Python 3.4 listed.

If you are on Linux your best bet is [compiling from source](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildHints) with support for your Python version (`./configure --with-python`).

Comment: I coundn't find GDAL bindings for python 3.4 here

Comment: You can however find GDAL 1.11.2 compiled with the Python 3.4 bindings.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt install gdal-bin python3-gdal
```

Comment: This line worked perfectly for me on digital ocean Ubuntu 16.4 server.

Answer (score 1):

I've developed [this post](http://www.machinalis.com/blog/python-for-geospatial-data-processing/) using GDAL 2.0.1 and Python 3.4
In the [README file of the repo](https://github.com/machinalis/satimg) you can see the links I used: